# Multiplayer finitely ultimatum game

Tags: game-theory

Imagine a 3 member legislature that must decide how to allocate an asset of unit value. There are
three rounds to the game and in each round a randomly assigned proposer must make an offer to
each of his fellow legislators. If an oer is accepted by two of the three legislators then the proposed
distribution is made and the game ends. If however no agreement is reached by the end of three
rounds then each legislator receives zero. Legislators payoffs are given by the share of the asset that
they obtain. Assume that for each legislator the current value of a share of the output received in
the next round is discounted by 0 < \delta < 1.
Find the subgame-perfect Nash equilibrium of this game.

Comment: looks like homework. what did you try?

Comment: I have just tried to use solution for pirates game, but in here number of person does not decrease and also legislator who prepare a proper is randomly selected. So i have trouble. there is 1/3 probability in terms of legislator selection. However, i cannot carry one step further :(

Comment: Suppose we are in the third round.  Can you solve that one?

Comment: if we are in the third round, then proposer offer 1 to one of the legislators and keep the rest of the value for himself to save majority and pass his offer. Am i right? Im not sure

Comment: if someone helps, i would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In the third round, the proposer should offer some small $x$ to one of the others and keep $1-x$. The value of this to each one is $\delta^2/3$ so in round $2$....